# How to change scrollbar style in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tooltip and I don't know how to change color on scrollbar.

```
.tooltip-inner {
  font-size: smaller;
  white-space: pre-line;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you add your html code

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

you can find all infomations right there [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/).
But remember that IE and Firefox doesn't support it.

Example as suggested:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

For your code try this:

```
.tooltip-inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:15px;
}

.tooltip-inner::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.tooltip-inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color:#2A2A2A;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:4px;
  border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I only changed body to your class, it should work like this.